# I can not enter the data for arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to enter `n` times values for `c` and `e` arrays. The following program doesn't allow me to even enter the value of 'n'. Could you tell me where is the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n,c[n],e[n];
   cin>>n;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c[i]>>e[i];
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is not defined but you are trying to use it in your array initialization

Comment: You should have at least posted the error you get. A compliant C++ compiler should probably error out about n not being a compile time constant.

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @PlasmaHH, program just stops working. it doesnt permits me to enter any value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int temp = 100; /*Random value*/
  int c[temp];
  int e[temp];
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>c[i]>>e[i];
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Now, I chose `temp` as 100, but you can do big as your `int` can store. Now, if `n` is lower than `temp`, your for cycle will let you save your values without troubles.

Answer (score 1):

"n" should be defined before using it to fix array size. Also, *const int* or constant should be used to declare array size not plain *int*.

In order to use plain datatype, you can initialize array dynamically like

```
vector<int> a(n); or
int a = new int[n]
```

Comment: Please do not recommend raw new, let alone malloc in C++ programs. The right thing to use is an `std::vector`

Comment: especially not allocating a single int initialized to `n`

Comment: Syntax of dynamic array is `new int[n]`, with brackets. Also, never use malloc when new is fine. Apart from that: use vector

Comment: Thats true vector is much safer added that as a top option. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int n,c[n],e[n];
```

This declaration creates arrays `c` and `e` on stack with random size, because `n` as an automatic variable is initialized with random value. Instead you need to dynamically create arrays on heap or use `std::vector`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int n;
    vector<int> v;
    std::cin >> n;
    v.resize( n);
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << v[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/QhgfNv

Comment: It actually should not even compile since no matter what n is, it is not a compile time constant as required by current standard C++.

Comment: Some compilers offer this as an extension (compiler extension are allowed so long as programs which would work already are unaffected)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Since the OP did not give an error message, its hard to tell if that might be the problem with his code or something else.

Comment: Huh? I am just referring to the claim that OP's code should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

In the line of

```
int n,c[n],e[n];
```

Computer don't know the exact value of 'n', so it can't alloc memory of array.

The simplest solution is create array with fixed number, and check n after you know the value of n as follows:

```
int n, c[1024], e[1024];
cin >> n;
if (n > 1024) { /* error */ }
```

The other way is malloc memory after u know the value of n:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int *c = new int[n];
int *e = new int[n];
xxxx
delete [] c;
delete [] e;
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using raw new/delete, a vector is the way to go. Also it isn't because "Computer don't know the exact value of 'n'"; the average contemporary computer has a value of n, which is just undetermined/unspecified. Standard C++ normally does not even compile this, and if it is using an extension, the arrays are of that unspecified size.